# view.officeapps.live.com open excel spreadsheet on a specific cell

Tags: view, live

I have an excel spreadsheet:
`<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=***" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>`
I want to open this Excel spreadsheet on a certain column (for example, "AH")
How can i do this? what parameters should I pass along with the request?

by when trying to search for information, found nothing

Answer (score 0):

you can use `activeCell` query parameter.

**Examples:**
`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=***&activeCell=A1`, to open with `First Cell` selected.
`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=***&activeCell=AH`, to open with `AH` selected.

And more complex:
`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=***&activeCell=%27Sheet2%27!AH`, to open sheet named `Sheet2` with `AH` selected.

**Note:**
Tested cyrillic sheet name with `activeCell=%27Лист 1%27!A1`, and it worked too.

**Sources:**
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/make-excel-office-365-open-at-cell-a1-or-create-a-hyperlink-to/m-p/991652
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773#ID0EDL